# Calling a function from member inside array in another array

Tags: c++, arrays, kernel

I was creating a custom operating system and I have a problem. I have an array of child components in an array of all opened windows. When I call a function CDraw (Component Draw) on the child array the system crashes with the message "General Protection Fault Detected".

Window array and code:

```
int openedWindows = 0;
Window* windows[128];

int OpenWindow(Window win) {
    windows[0][openedWindows] = win;
    openedWindows++;
    return openedWindows-1;
};
void CloseWindow(int index) {
    for(int i = index+1; i < 127; i++) {
        if(i != 127)
            windows[0][i] = windows[0][i-1];
        else
            windows[0][i] = Window();
    }
    openedWindows--;
};
void CloseAllWindows() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
        windows[0][i] = Window();
    }
    openedWindows = 0;
};

/*Draw Windows*/
for(int i = 0; i < openedWindows; i++)
{
    windows[0][i].Update();
}
```

Where I call the code:

```
Window wnd = Window("Window");
wnd.Update();
Button btn = Button(wnd, "Hello");
btn.CPosition = Point(10, 10);
btn.BackColor = Color(MediumTurquoise);
btn.parent = &wnd;
btn.parent->AddComponent(btn);
btn.Update();
Button btn2 = Button(wnd, "H2");
btn2.CPosition = Point(100, 100);
btn2.BackColor = Color(Red);
btn2.parent = &wnd;
btn2.parent->AddComponent(btn2);
btn2.Update();  

OpenWindow(wnd);
```

Componet code:

```
int childIndex = 0;
BaseGuiComponent* children[128];

int BaseGuiComponent::AddComponent(BaseGuiComponent baseGuiComponent) {
    children[0][childIndex] = baseGuiComponent;
    childIndex++;
    return childIndex-1;
};
void BaseGuiComponent::RemoveComponent(int index) {
    for(int i = index+1; i < 127; i++) {
        if(i != 127)
            children[0][i] = children[0][i-1];
        else
            children[0][i] = BaseGuiComponent();
    }
    childIndex--;
};
void BaseGuiComponent::ClearComponents() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
        children[0][i] = BaseGuiComponent();
    }
    childIndex = 0;
};

//List components and Update();
void BaseGuiComponent::DrawChildren() {
    for(int i = 0; i < childIndex; i++) {
        children[0][i].Update();
    }
};
```

Drawing code:

```
void BaseGuiComponent::CDraw() {
    if (strcmp(type,"Window",128)) {
        Draw->DrawWindow(BackColor.GetHexColor(), CPosition.X, CPosition.Y, CSize.Width, CSize.Height, 2, CText, WindowStyle, Draw->GetScreenBounds());
        DrawChildren();
    } else if (strcmp(type,"Button",128)) {
        Draw->FillRect(BackColor.GetHexColor(), CGlobalPosition.X*4, CGlobalPosition.Y, CSize.Width*4, CSize.Height, parent->bound/* Conflicting code */);
        Draw->PRINTAT(ForeColor.GetHexColor(),CText, CGlobalPosition.X + nabs(CSize.Width - svlen(CText))/2,CGlobalPosition.Y + nabs(CSize.Height-16)/2, bound);
    }
};
```

All help is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Emulators like QEMU do allow attaching a debugger AFAIK.

Comment: A declaration like `Window* windows[128];` creates space for pointers but not for array elements.

Comment: You created "a custom operating system" and that "system crashes with the message "General Protection Fault Detected"." - really? Well, typically memory protection units are used to protect different OS tasks from each other. If you received a protection fault message, this means that the task that caused it has tried to access some memory that didn't "belong" to it but to another task. Please find out which access triggered that protection fault crash, who owns the accessed resource, and which task has tried the forbidden access. Then, you must use inter-task communication measures in between

Comment: @TRPh. Thanks. I did not understand you at first but then I made ```Window windows[128];``` to ```Window windows[128]``` and the issue vanished.